# ' import sklearn as sk' does not work in a python script file which I give to ipython, but it works in interactive ipython

Tags: python, scikit-learn

In a python script file I have:

```
import sklearn
iris=sklearn.datasets.load_iris()
```

This works:

```
$ ipython <this script file>
```

But now I do in the script file:

```
import sklearn as sk
iris=sk.datasets.load_iris()
```

If I do the same as above, I see:

```
AttributeError: module 'sklearn' has no attribute 'datasets'
```

This is what I do not understand. Also in interactive ipython the last import and assignment work!

Also:

```
import scipy as sp
p1=sp.special.expit(Phi@w)
```

works in a script file (given to ipython)! Looks like the same as above with sklearn where it did not work.

Comment: have u restarted kernal??

Comment: `datasets` is a sub-package of `sklearn` so you have to use `from sklearn import datasets`.

Comment: @yudhiesh Okay  but look at my example I added with scipy. That works. What is the difference?

Comment: `special` isn't a sub-package that is why it works.

Comment: @yudhiesh Okay. But why does it work in interactive python?